# Is it possible to make the FOSUserBundle "error" variable global to all twig files

Tags: symfony, twig

I am using the FOSUserBundle in Symfony 3.4. Everything is working correctly. I am overriding the FOSUserBundle templates with my own. The way I am checking if the user failed to login because of an incorrect password or email is this way:

**login.html.twig**

```
{% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}
...Some html nothing fancy
                {% if error %}
                    <div>{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
                           {% endif %}

    ....Rest of file content

    </div>
```

This runs no problem. The user of course is redirected to the index page after failure handled via my security file. 
However, I tried using the if statement above in  the index.html.twig, it thinks it is undefined. I want to use it so I can for example, when the user gets redirected to index page for my customized message to appear. Is there a for the "error" variable in that twig file to be made global to all twig files when it gets set?

Answer (score 0):

The FosUserBundle stores errors in the symfony flashBag you can use this code

```
    {% if app.request.hasPreviousSession %}
        {% for type, messages in app.session.flashbag.all() %}
            {% for message in messages %}
                <div class="flash-{{ type }}">
                    {{ message }}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
```

You can look this the template of FosUserBundle https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/views/layout.html.twig

Or more globaly https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#flash-messages

If you want to change the default errors message, you should rather replace the default translations of the FosUserBundle.